# How to restrict ssh port forwarding, without denying it?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

Suppose I have created an account whose login shell is actually a script which does not permit an interactive login, and only allows a very limited, specific set of commands to be remotely executed.

Nevertheless, `ssh` allows the user of this account to forward ports, which is a hole.

Now, the twist is that I actually want that account to set up a specific port forwarding configuration when the `ssh` session is established. But it must be impossible configure arbitrary port forwarding.

(It is an acceptable solution if the permitted port forwarding configuration is unconditionally established as part of the every session.)

Comment: If nobody comes forward in a couple of days, I will accept my own answer. And perhaps get working on it.

Comment: If you keep it unaccepted/open for some time then you will receive little more attention. Some people like spending weekend at [somewhere else](http://www.metsa.fi/sivustot/metsa/en/Recreation/Hiking/Sivut/OutdoorActivities.aspx) than SO :)

Comment: My original answer was a proposed patch, but existing features in OpenSSH do the job.

Comment: Oops, this belongs on serverfault, doesn't it! It's easy to forget that "superuser" here doesn't mean "root" or "sysadmin".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out, OpenSSH has a feature for this, for restricting `-L` style opens on the server side. The feature is available in two ways.

1. In the server configuration file there is a `PermitOpen` option. This option can be used to specify hosts and ports for which forwards can be established. This option can be used inside a `Match` block, so it can be restricted by user, group, or hostname or IP address pattern.
2. In an `authorized_keys` file, options can be associated with a particular key. There is a `permitopen` option which works similarly to the server-config one.

**Notes/Limitations:**

- The option `AllowTcpForwarding` disables all forwarding in both directions, preventing listening ports from being set up on the server, as well as active forwards.
- There is no `PermitOpen` access control for `-R` style connections. This is probably okay. What it means is that the users can use `ssh` to open various non-privileged ports for listening on the server. Where these connect to on the other side of the SSH connection is the client's problem. If we restrict forwarding in the `-L` direction, the user has no way of using those `-R` ports (at least not through `ssh`, if that user is not able to create an arbitrary interactive session).
- There doesn't seem to be a way to create an empty list of permitted opens, to prevent users from making any `-L` style connections whatsoever. However, a workaround is to use a harmless, nonexistent or impossible host name, such as the empty string. Concretely, `permitopen=":1234"` does the trick.

Comment: Since I can live without fine grained access control on `-R`, this works for me.

Comment: `PermitOpen none` works in the sshd config to prevent `-L` style connections. However the option `permitopen=...` in the `authorized_keys` file *does not* recognize `none` as keyword for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

> There doesn't seem to be a way to create an empty list of permitted
>   opens, to prevent users from making any -L style connections
>   whatsoever. However, a workaround is to use a harmless, nonexistent or
>   impossible host name, such as the empty string. Concretely,
>   permitopen=":1234" does the trick.

An argument of “any” can be used to remove all restrictions and permit any forwarding requests.  An argument of “none” can be used to prohibit all forwarding requests.  By default all port forwarding requests are permitted.