# Will no-port-forwarding in authorized_keys disable all port forwarding?

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding, openssh, ssh-tunnel

Here port forwarding I means **ALL** kinds of port forwarding, `-D` dynamic port forwarding(for socks4 and socks5 now), `-L` local port forwarding to remote, `-R` remote port forwarding to local. How to fine grained control them separately? I know there is also `permitopen` option to permit only specified forwarding to host and port.

And I want to know `AllowTcpForwarding` in sshd_config will do `-L` or `-R`, but not `-D`?

How to allow `-D`, but not `-L` or `-R`, or this is not possible? I have added`command="/bin/echo no-command"` to the authorized_keys file.

1. [Allow user to set up an SSH tunnel, but nothing else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021/allow-user-to-set-up-an-ssh-tunnel-but-nothing-else)
2. [How to restrict ssh port forwarding, without denying it?](https://superuser.com/questions/516417/how-to-restrict-ssh-port-forwarding-without-denying-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allowing `-D` but not `-L` is not possible, since they only differ on the client – as far as the protocol is concerned, both are exactly the same thing (they both open `direct-tcpip` channels over SSH).

The only difference between them is how the ssh client decides which address to connect to (either specified in the command line, or obtained over SOCKS).

Comment: Yes, -L will forward local_addr:local_port to remote_host:remote_port, and -D will forward local_addr:local_port to unknown_host:unknown_port. So unknown_host:unknow_port will definite contains remote_host:remote_port?

Comment: Doesn't matter if it does or not. The server does not care. The server _does not_ receive anything like "prepare a -D tunnel please". The server only receives individual requests like "open a tunnel to host:port right now", and they're identical for both -D and -L.

Comment: OK. Thanks. How about disabling -R using `permitopen` ?

Comment: That should be possible, since it's in a different direction, but I can't find an option for it.