# How secure is allowing an untrusted third party to forward one of their ports via OpenSSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, security, port-forwarding

I'd like to SSH into a machine of an untrusted third party.
Their machine is behind a firewall.

I'm thinking I should allow them to forward their SSH port to my publicly addressed server, via `ssh -R`.

Assuming I gave the third party `/bin/false` as a login shell, what sorts of vulnerabilities would I expose myself to?

Comment: Why can't they give you inbound access through their firewall? If they want you there it doesn't seem an unreasonable request. If they don't want you there... well...

Answer (score 0):

If you allow SSH into your machine from an untrusted source, even without a login shell and port forwarding enabled, they can establish port forwarding and reach services on the machine that are accessible via the loopback interface only. Sometimes such services are either unprotected or have weak protection (e.g. database servers, sendmail, etc.).

For more details refer to [How to restrict ssh port forwarding, without denying it?](https://superuser.com/questions/516417/how-to-restrict-ssh-port-forwarding-without-denying-it)